# Show error message from PL/SQL procedure to the client

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, plsql

I have a `try` block in my C# client which executes an Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure and a `catch` block using `Exception` class.

In the stored procedure, if a particular condition is encountered during data processing, an exception is raised using `raise_application_error`.

**Example:** `raise_application_error(-20001, myErrMsg)`

I then want to catch this exception and show this particular message in the C# client as it is.

And for all the other database related errors (e.g. constraint failure, connection errors) I want to catch and them show in my custom error message in the C# client.

In my `catch` block, should I search for the string `ORA-20001` in the exception message string and then propagate it to the client as it is to determine if the above exception is being thrown from the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch an Oracle Exception if you can.

```
  try
    {
      cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM myable";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
       //Put your ORA-20001 logic here, or call a common method as shown
       HandleOracleException(ex);
    }
```

In the catch handler, check to see if the number is 20001, and then take appropriate action.

Here are some properties of OracleException

**DataSource** 
Specifies the TNS name that contains the information for connecting to an Oracle instance

**Errors** 
Specifies a collection of one or more OracleError objects that contain information about 
exceptions generated by the Oracle database

**InnerException** 
Inherited from Exception

**Message**
Specifies the error messages that occur in the exception

**Number** 
Specifies the Oracle error number

**Procedure**
Specifies the stored procedure that cause the exception

**Source**
Specifies the name of the data provider that generates the error

**StackTrace**
Inherited from Exception

**TargetSite**
Inherited from Exception

Link For More Info:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleExceptionClass.htm